# Why does "override val" not exist in f#?

Tags: inheritance, functional-programming, f#

Why is there no such thing as "override val" in F#?
In the language spec I see it on page 155
https://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/4.1/FSharpSpec-4.1-latest.pdf

But it doesn't look like it made it into the syntax:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/inheritance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a thing called `override val` in F#, it *did* make it into the language. The example on page 155 compiles:

```
type MyBase () =
    abstract Property : string with get, set
    default val Property = "default" with get, set
type MyDerived() =
    inherit MyBase()
    override val Property = "derived" with get, set
```

Typing this into FSI shows that the overridden `val` is properly accessed and returned:

```
> type MyBase =
  new: unit -> MyBase
  abstract Property: string
  override Property: string
type MyDerived =
  inherit MyBase
  new: unit -> MyDerived
  override Property: string

> MyDerived().Property;;
val it: string = "derived"
```

I agree though, that the docs should also mention it. At best you could say it is said implicitly, where (under "Interfaces") it says that you can use `val` or members with `override` or `default`. This should certainly be improved.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I should have tried that!

I think I'm struggling to figure out how to make that abstract property have a type which is a function, let's say a function that takes a string and returns a string, and then making the override still work.

Comment: Something like this:

[<AbstractClass>]
type MyBase () =
    abstract Property : string->string with get, set
type MyDerived() =
    inherit MyBase()
    override val Property = (fun s -> s) with get, set

Comment: @Eugene a more common approach in F# (or any FP) is not to use OO properties to contain functions, but to pass them as arguments to (pure) functions that need access to such function. I don't know your use case, but I do know it is pretty uncommon to do that. Alternatively, you may consider using delegates as types for your properties if you do need this.

Comment: I am using a memoize function to help save the results of certain functions.
In subclasses, I repeatedly have the following:
member val SomeFunc = this.Memoize SomeSlowFunc

Then I also want to override certain base class functions, ideally the syntax becomes:
member val SomeFunc = this.Memoize SomeSlowFunc
override val SomeBaseFunc = this.Memoize SomeOtherSlowFunc

Instead, I have to do something like:
let localFunc = this.Memoize SomeOtherSlowFunc
override this.SomeFunc(param1, param2) = localFunc

Which feels more verbose/sloppy.

Comment: @Eugene that’ll work, but with classes that’s gonna be a lot of extra work. With currying and a memoize function you could just do `let memof = memo f` and you have a memoized function of `f` through currying. But yeah, either approach works in the end.